# Download attachment issue with IE6-8 wih no SSL

Tags: internet-explorer, email-attachments

I'm facing an issue with file download with IE6-8 in non ssl environment. I've seen a lot of articles about the IE attachment download issue with ssl.

As per the articles I tried to set the values of Pragma, Cache-Control headers, but still no luck with it.

These are my response headers

```
Cache-Control: private, max-age=5
Date: Tue, 25 May 2010 11:06:02 GMT
Pragma: private
Content-Length: 40492
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: Attachment;Filename="file name.pdf"
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
```

I've set the header values after going through some of these sites 
    [KB 812935](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812935)
    [KB 316431](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;316431)
But these items are related to SSL.

I've checked the response body and headers using [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/), the response body is proper.

I'm using window.open(url, "_blank") to download the file, if I change it to window.open(url, "_parent") or change the "Content-Disposition" to 'inline;Filename="file name.pdf"' it works fine.

Please  help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not with the file download headers. I was downloading the file in the callback of a async AJAX method.

It looks like this is not allowed in IE, I just made the AJAX call to be a synchronized call and it started to work.

Is there any other solution for this issue than making the AJAX call to be synchronized?

Comment: Would be glad to hear if you ever find an alternative.